# How to take advantage of USB3.0 speed for VHD of Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v

i created a Hyper-V VM which has it's vhd on a external usb3.0 disk. But the vhd works way too slow. Normally i see around 98Mb/s read/write speed from the hdd if i use it from my main OS. But it is almost 2-3Mb/s read/write speed on my VM. How can i bump the speed of external disk for my Hyper-V VM ?

Comment: Is this speed normal for USB2? In that case it might be a driver problem.

Comment: you mean driver in a VM ?

Comment: I am no expert. My guess is that the VM doesn't use the host OS drivers, but its own. That would explain this. So check if Hyper-V supports USB3.

Comment: Maybe you can symlink the vhd folder on the external disk so that the VM thinks it's internal on the host OS? I'm no Windows expert in this regard, so am not sure that this will work.